# Assign friendly name to Django model field

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there a way I can assign a friendly name to a database column in Django? I'm looking for something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, friendly_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, friendly_name='Last Name')
```

In order to access in a manner similar to this:

```
for f in Person._meta.get_fields():
    print(f.friendly_name)
```

Output:

```
First Name
Last Name
```

I am using Django 2.1 and PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.verbose_name) field attribute.